# Can you split a 3 phase outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

To be clear. I have a 3 phase outlet, that a commercial oven is plugged into,
and want to make another. Can I run wire from the existing plug/outlet and make a new plug/outlet from it. With the ability to use both appliances at the same time

Comment: Probably not, since big outlets like that are usually sized just big enough to power what's currently plugged into them.  But it's possible someone oversized this power drop, or the oven that's there now draws less power than the original, so there's a (small) chance it could be made to work like you're hoping.  To know that, we'd need to know what size breaker is feeding the oven currently, and the nameplate ratings of both your old and proposed new oven.  More likely, though, you'll need to make a new wiring run back to the panel for the new oven.

Comment: This is going to go into the Tap rules it may be possible, as Nate asks all the load information, Plus your location will be needed what is allowed changes with location. In the US this would most probably be a commercial job and that almost always requires a licensed electrician.

Comment: Maybe. It depends on a bunch of things.  If you'd like to share some of those things with us, we could discuss it.

Comment: How many kW is the existing outlet, and how many kW is the new load you're planning to put on it? What size is the circuit breaker on the circuit? Is the new load resistive heat, a motor, a factory-built appliance, ...?

Comment: And to add to the question by @ThreePhaseEel what gauge wire connects the existing outlet back to the breaker in the service panel.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will look to see if I can find the information .